# Email Alert sent to Related Contact Not Merging Contact Fields

Tags: email-template, email-alert, merge-field

[image]I've got a workflow that runs every time a `Foo__c` is inserted and sends an `Email Alert` to the `Related Contact` `Foo__c.Contact__c`.

According to this: https://developer.salesforce.com/forums/?id=906F00000008uu1IAA , I should be able to reference the `Related Contact` by writing `{!Contact.FirstName}` in the Email Template. However, this is not working. The space where I've put that merge field at comes back blank when sent to me.

I know a potential solution here is to create a formula field on my `Foo__c` object that exposes the contact's first name, but that seems like not a best practice.

Can someone confirm which way I should be doing this or explain why that developer.salesforce.com post indicates that `{!Contact.FirstName}` should work. Is that post wrong?

Answer (score 1):

From within workflow, the related contact should already be in the context of the workflow. That's why `{!Contact.FirstName}` should work.

However, if the field isn't populated in the contact's record, workflow won't be able to enter data for it in the template. I suggest you test your template with a record you know has valid data in the `{!Contact.FirstName}` field. Unless you absolutely need the FirstName only, it would be preferable to use `{!Contact.Name}` since by default, only the `LastName` is a required field in an org.

Comment: I tried putting all 3 of {!Contact}, {!Contact.Name} and {!Contact.FirstName} in my email template. None of these worked and all came through as blank. Both the first/last name are populated in the contact record.

Comment: A couple of questions here. Are fields from your `foo__c` object showing up in your email? In your workflow, did you define the contacts to use in the email alert in workflow as beginning from `Contact` object or beginning relative to the `foo__c` object record?

Comment: Yes fields from the Foo__c are showing up in the email. The email alert is defined beginning relative to the Foo__c object record. See attached image in original question.

Comment: Did you update (click on edit at bottom left of your post) to include your image? If not, I don't see any link to it. It sounds like you did it properly in your workflow. Have you tried changing your template to use `{!Foo__c.Contact__r.FirstName}`? It could be that in the post you cited, a specific contact was referenced. It can be done either way in workflow; esp if more than one contact is being referenced.

Comment: It's blank that way as well.

Comment: Looking at your screen capture, you may want to try selecting `Email Field` in the `Foo Template` to see if that doesn't give you the results you're looking for.  With not being able to see your org or template it can be difficult to troubleshoot these issues.

Comment: try adding {!telatedTo.Name}